# LDAP - How to define a directory which reprensents IT assets inventory

Tags: ldap

My goal is to build a directory that would represent the inventory of our IT assets.

I believe LDAP is the right way to go since it is built as an hierarchy and search can be done on branch and attributes. However, my experience with LDAP is somewhat limited. I've installed a server, configured it, added few entries and played with the querying quite a bit but i'm struggling with the definition of the structure.

Here is an example of what I would like to create:

```
Org
  Servers
  |--Server1 
     |--VM1
       |--Application1
       |--Application2
     |--VM2
        |--Application3
        |--Application4
     |--Application5
  |--...
  Users
  |--Joe
  |--Jane
  |--Bob
  Groups
  |--Admins
  |--Auditors
  |--...
```

Also each [server, vm, application] would have an administrator, operator, users, etc. Some kind of reference to the Users or Groups part.

Is there any schema implementing this kind of relation? If not what object class should I use or create? How would you approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created our own schemas, and am probably going to continue doing so when new needs pop up.

I try to inherit from suitable RFC schemas, and often just have to pick some new attributes on top of when the RFC objectclass already has. Sometimes it's useful to define your own attributetypes to get naming to work. Like having device (already has serialNumber) + manufacturer, model, dateAcquired, warrantyEnds.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't think this is very useful way of doing this. If you're doing IT in this century (or most of the last one) your users and groups are already in an LDAP hierarchy. If you need them represented in another one, then you can arrange an import, sync, or other sort of "truing-up" process. Server and applications, on the other hand, aren't particularly useful when in an LDAP hierarchy, because you can't (easily) use it to represent multiple dependencies. Read up on CMDB implementations and how you can use them to help assess impact and risk.

Answer (score 1):

I use 'device' for the servers and 'account' plus 'simpleSecurityObject' for the applications.